# PrepareAppBundle Task Failed Unexpectedly - Xamarin Forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022

Things were working fine before but all of a sudden I can't build and deploy my Xamarin Forms 5 app to my iPhone connected to my Windows 11 machine via USB cable.

Initial error I got was the following:

> The 'HotRestart.Tasks.DetectSigningIdentity' task failed unexpectedly.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

I then tried to rebuild the project and I got the following error:

> The "PrepareAppBundle" task failed unexpectedly.

Here's a screenshot of that:

[image]

To make sure it's not my project that's causing the error, I created a fresh new Xamarin Forms app and tried to look at it on my iPhone without changing a single line anywhere in the new app and I ended up with the same exact errors above.

I'm on the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 - version 17.1.3 and my laptop runs Windows 11 with all the latest updates.

I'm able to run the app on Android Simulator AND a physical Android device connected to my laptop via the same USB port. It just seems to be failing on iPhone.

Any idea what's causing this issue?

Comment: Having a similar issue today after updating to Visual Studio 17.1.3 - must be an issue wiith Visual Studio?

Comment: Quite possible because I just upgraded to 17.1.3 yesterday and discovered this issue after that.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same issue after updating Visual Studio + Xcode + Xamarin Runtime.  The same update also broke iOS emulation, leaving me completely unable to work.

Comment: I submitted this issue via the built-in bug submission in VS. Also let some product managers at Microsoft know about it. She promised to get the engineering team look into it. You can follow it here at the link below. Also feel free to let them know you're having the same issue so that they understand the pressing nature of this issue. Here's the link: https://twitter.com/SamUresin/status/1509948928753557504?s=20&t=siixVe6LSA3NRjyKE5yPZA

Comment: Same problem after updating VS 2022 to 17.1.3. Now using VS 2019 which is working :)

Comment: @Manik: That's great news!  Which version of VS 2019 is confirmed working?

Comment: If you up-vote the issue I submitted to VS team, it may get more attention. Please make sure you're signed into Developer Community before clicking the link otherwise you can't see it. For some reason, Microsoft is only showing these issues to authenticated users. Here's the link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/PrepareAppBundle-Task-Failed-Unexpectedl/10003481

Comment: @Sam I saw that on twitter already, but like the other user, I'm unable to access that link. And yes, I'm signed in.

Comment: I tried VS 2019 last night; no luck.  Based on [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-load-Apple-certificates/1692185#T-N10007099) it sounds like the issue is that Apple changed one of their APIs without telling anyone, and MS is having a hard time fixing it because there is no API documentation at all.  Neat.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft As I understand it, this was the original issue back in 2018 when it first appeared. Then it was fixed. Looks like it just came back to life with VS 17.1.3. The issue I reported to VS Community has been triaged and assigned to an engineering team. Hopefully, we'll get VS 17.1.4 soon with the fix. Here's the link to the related GitHub issue: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/5277

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Sorry mate I didnt see your comment my bad. I am able to keep dev going on Version 16.11.11 VS 2019. My stack is Xamarin Forms Net Standard Lib 2.1 C#8. Are you having any issues with VS 2019?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just upgraded Visual Studio to 17.1.4 and the problem is FIXED!!!

Comment: Thanks @sam just updated mine and its all working...

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Xamarin.Forms for all projects and it worked. This was after weeks of searching for a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Also happened to me. Did not find a better way than reinstalling Visual Studio Community with the newest version 17.1.3. Seems the error is gone since then. Visual Studio seems to be very unfriendly for Android and iOS development..

Regards

Comment: I tried that too but unfortunately, it didn't do anything in my case. I'm still getting the same errors. Interesting to note that Microsoft seems to be keeping their install packages up-to-date. After removing VS 2022 completely from my computer, reinstalling it all over again installed 17.1.3 without needing any updates.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error after updating Visual Studio to version 17.1.3

You have 2 options to solve this:

1- If you have mac, pair to it and just rebuild the project the error will gone.

2- unload [YourProject].IOS, this will help till you get a Mac device.

(to unload project, Go to Solution explorer >> right click on [YourProject].IOS >> unload project)

Comment: I have a mac to pair with, it still doesn't work.